# Метод app\controllers\MainController::indexAction не найден

Tags: php

Такая проблема, с php

Код MainController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;


class MainController
{
  public function indexAction(){

  }
}
```

Использую phpStorm

Comment: Случайно не в регистре символов дело?

Comment: а и за чего ошибка может быть?

Comment: Из за того, что так написано. Вообще, хотелось бы увидеть саму ошибку, как она есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас объявлен `namespace App\Controllers`, а пытаетесь вызвать `app\controllers\...`. В документации php, есть метка "**Note**: Namespace names are case-insensitive." - она означает что пространства имен регистрозависимые, вам нужно прописать `namespace app\controllers` в нижнем регистре.

Так же существуют стандарты написания кода, в которых подробно расписывается, как должен выглядеть ваш код, его структура и логические названия пакетов, объектов, переменных, и т.д. Сейчас ваш `namespace App\Controllers` соответствует стандарту [psr-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) - но дело уже ваше какой регистр использовать, есть просто рекомендации по написанию, которым следуют большинство разработчиков - это некие договоренности, "правила пунктуации и грамматики" для каждого языка, чтобы следующий разработчик, который столкнется с вашим кодом, максимально понимал что он делает и для чего нужен.